# How to find parent component in code base - angular 5?

Tags: angular

I want to find name of the parent component from child component. Is it possible to get name of the parent component from child component?

Comment: search for selector of child component in html file. There are chanced it might it used in parent component html file to pass data as `@Input`.

Comment: use nativeelement from your child component which is a instace of your parent component then you can do it

Comment: I have tried to pass data between parent to child and child to parent using respective `@input` and `@output` event emitter. But not working in my application. Cannot find the reason. So that I should confirming child component which parent it is pointing out.@candidJ

Comment: can you please create a stackblitz demo? it's hard to comment out why parent child communication is not occuring using `@Input` and `@Output`. do you get any error msg ?

Comment: Finally I resolved using service to component communication using observable.

Answer (score 0):

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/parent-child-component-example)

HTML:

parent component:

```
<hello [parent]="'parentCoponent'" (output)="outputEvent($event)" ></hello>
<p>
  Hello My Child is {{childComponent}}
</p>
```

child component:

```
<h1>Hello My Parent Is {{parent}}</h1>
```

TS:

parent component:

```
import { Component, ViewChild,Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef , OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  childComponent: any;

  ngOnInit(){
  }

  outputEvent(event){
    console.log(event)
    this.childComponent = event
  }
}  console.log(event)
    this.childComponent = event
  }
}
```

child component:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello My Parent Is {{parent}}</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() parent : any;
  @Output() output = new  EventEmitter<any>()

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log("Input:" + this.parent)
    this.output.emit('childComponent');
  }

}
```